# Multiple file i/o with apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

My requirement is as follows: I need to unzip a file and read metadata information from an unpacked xml file. This would be done in the `xmlToObjectMapper`. Now i need to enrich the metadata with data from multiple other xmls which are located in zip files. That means I have to unpack them read them and attach the information to my `MetadataHolder` object. I wanted to implement this in the commented line `pollEnrich`.

```
from("file://{{first.directory}}?noop=true&idempotent=true")
        .split(new ZipSplitter())
            .streaming()
                .choice()
                    .when(header("zipFileName").isEqualTo("metadata.xml"))
                        .multicast()
                            .to("file://{{first.directory}}/Working?fileName=$simple{file:onlyname.noext}/${header.zipFileName}")
                            .pipeline()
                                .convertBodyTo(String.class, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.name())
                                .bean("xmlToObjectMapper", "readAllRequiredMetadata")
                                //.pollEnrich("", 0, new MetadataHolderAggregationStrategy())
                            .end()
                        .end()
                .end()
            .to("file://{{first.directory}}/Working?fileName=$simple{file:onlyname.noext}/${header.zipFileName}")
        .end()
    .end()
    ;
```

But now I am stuck because I get the following stacktrace:

```
org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: java.lang.String but has value: org.apache.camel.dataformat.zipfile.ZipInputStreamWrapper@2c52254b of type: org.apache.camel.dataformat.zipfile.ZipInpu
tStreamWrapper on: Message[id]. Caused by: Error during type conversion from type: java.lang.String to the required type: java.lang.String with value [Body is instance of java.io.I
nputStream] due java.io.IOException: Stream closed. Exchange[id]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException - Error during type conversion from type: java.lang.String to
 the required type: java.lang.String with value [Body is instance of java.io.InputStream] due java.io.IOException: Stream closed]
```

I thought that multicast will implicitly cache the stream and send it to all endpoints...

So can anyone tell me why this is happening? And is my solution of the requirement a valid way or do I have to split the requirement into multiple routes?

**EDIT1:**

I solved the problem with the exception by adding `.streamCaching()` to the route. Because of other problems i had to alter the original route a little bit.

```
from("file://{{first.directory}}?noop=true&idempotent=true")
        .streamCaching()
        .split(new ZipSplitter())
            .streaming()
                .choice()
                    .when(header("zipFileName").isEqualTo("metadata.xml"))
                        .multicast()
                            .to("file://{{first.directory}}/Working?fileName=$simple{file:onlyname.noext}/${header.zipFileName}")
                            .pipeline()
                                .convertBodyTo(String.class, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.name())
                                .bean("xmlToObjectMapper", "readAllRequiredMetadata")
                                .pollEnrich("file://{{second.directory}}?&noop=true&idempotent=true", 0, new MetadataHolderAggregationStrategy())
                            .end()
                        .end()
                    .endChoice()
                    .otherwise()
                        .to("file://{{first.directory}}/Working?fileName=$simple{file:onlyname.noext}/${header.zipFileName}")
                .end()
        .end()
    .end()
    ;
```

But now I have problems with `pollEnrich`. The newExchange in my `MetadataHolderAggregationStrategy` is always null. How can I solve this?

**EDIT2:**

Finally i found a solution. I had to use `enrich` instead of `pollEnrich` and  implement the whole i/o in java (`readAllRequiredMetadata2`). My final solution looks like this:

```
from("file://{{first.directory}}?noop=true&idempotent=true")
        .streamCaching()
        .split(new ZipSplitter())
            .streaming()
                .choice()
                    .when(header("zipFileName").isEqualTo("metadata.xml"))
                        .multicast()
                            .to("file://{{first.directory}}/Working?fileName=$simple{file:onlyname.noext}/${header.zipFileName}")
                            .pipeline()
                                .convertBodyTo(String.class, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.name())
                                .bean("xmlToObjectMapper", "readAllRequiredMetadata")
                                .enrich("direct:readResources", 0, new MetadataHolderAggregationStrategy())
                                //Go on processing the enriched metadata
                            .end()
                        .end()
                    .endChoice()
                    .otherwise()
                        .to("file://{{first.directory}}/Working?fileName=$simple{file:onlyname.noext}/${header.zipFileName}")
                .end()
        .end()
    .end()
    ;

from("direct:readResources")
   .bean("xmlToObjectMapper", "readAllRequiredMetadata2")
.end()
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For stream-like data, you probably need to use stream caching. It's off by default so the second endpoint will not have it as it was already read by the first one. You can check more details there: http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html

Comment: Thx for the hint for stream caching